# Power up problem maybe PSU or powerswitch

Tags: power-supply, boot

I have computer that occasionally fails to start up. It has the following symptoms:

1. You can push the power up button and nothing happens.
2. You can push the power up button and it looks it starting to power up then it shutdowns after few seconds. I don't even see the POST screen.
3. After it does power up it won't shut down in middle of boot, but may power off suddenly after few hours of work and then symptoms one and two are come again.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is a "powerswitch"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try ensuring that all vents and fans are clean and dust free to rule out a thermal/overheat problem, but since the problem seems to occur from cold, I'd suspect it's the power supply and would test by trying another one. If this proves inconclusive, it may be an ageing/faulty motherboard or attached device such as a hard disk or optical drive.

Comment: How does a hard drive would stop the power up?Though a PC is about 2.5 years old but I still don't see a connection

Comment: I would second a good cleaning, and see if a friend has a power supply you can borrow to test with. Also, test by disconnecting everything that's not necessary (harddrives, dvd/cd drives, add-in cards other than the graphics card) to reduce the number of variables.

Comment: The problem it could work about a week or two without any problems and suddenly the cycle start over again

Comment: As for how a hard drive/optical drive might interfere, it is very remotely possible that a short in the powerline from the PSU to the hard drive might cause the circuit breaker to trip, but that's extremely unlikely.  But yea, it's probably a bad PSU.